# How to use AutoFac in Web API to resolve a service at runtime?

Tags: c#, runtime, autofac, webapi

I have an API (`eg: ItemController.cs`) which would obtain the Authorization Token from the Request Header at run time. With the Token, then only I pass into my Service Class (`eg: ServiceItem.cs`).

Here's how I did.

1. At the Startup.cs, I register my ServiceItem

   ```
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
   builder.RegisterType<ServiceItem>();
   container = builder.Build(); //Note that, my container is a static variable
   ```
2. In my API, I resolve it in this way:

   ```
   [Authorize]
   [Route("GetData")]
   [HttpGet]
   public IHttpActionResult GetData([FromUri] Filter filter)
   {
    using (var scope = Startup.container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
       var serviceItem = Startup.container.Resolve<ServiceItem>(
               new NamedParameter("token", Request.GetHeader("Authorization"))
           );
       return Ok(serviceItem.getItem(filter)); //filter is a param from webAPI
    }
   }
   ```

Question:

Is this how the Autofac normally work in web API? First, i am using a global static `IContainer`. Second, the codes look repetitive if i expose a few more functions.

I was thinking to resolve the `ServiceItem` in the constructor of the API. But the authorization token is not available yet.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**P.S.:**

Here's my `ServiceItem` which, in the constructor, has a param 'token'

```
     public class ServiceItem
     {
          public string token;
          public ServiceItem(string token)
          {
              this.token = token;
          }

          public void doSomething()
          {
              //based on token, do processing
          }
      }
```

Comment: You need to set the [DependencyResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) to the AutoFac container.

Comment: @john Thanks for pointing out the Dependency Resolver. I also found it in [Autofac Doc](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#set-the-dependency-resolver). By the way, how to resolve it during runtime?

Comment: You can put the services you need in the controller constructor.

Comment: Now i understand and have tested. By using DependencyResolver, it avoids the use of 'static' variable in my sample. However, not sure if i have mistaken something. This would only work if my `ServiceItem` has no param. If I would like to resolve the Service with a runtime information such as a token from the Request Header, how is it performed?

Comment: You can create [delegate factories](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) and inject them.

Comment: OMG i hope there are more code samples on this. After trial and error now i understand how it works. With Delegate Factories, although i still register my `ServiceItem`, it is actually the Factory to be injected in the constructor. Then, in my own API function, i use that Factory to call the method `Invoke`

Comment: There are many code samples for AutoFac, although I find some of the best resources are previous questions here on [SO].

Comment: Btw, Thanks honestly. This paves my way to understanding how AutoFac works for runtime situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bad idea to refer to a static container within your startup class. That way, you introduce tight coupling between the controller and the startup. Your controller dependencies should be satisfied by constructor parameters. Take at http://docs.autofac.org/en/v4.0.0/integration/aspnetcore.html

The `Startup.ConfigureServices` method can optionally return a `IServiceProvider` instance, which allows you to plug-in Autofac into the ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection framework:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();

  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IMyType>();
  builder.Populate(services);
  this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

  return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
}
```

After initializing your container, constructor parameters will be automatically resolved by Autofac:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly IMyType theType;
    public MyController(IMyType theType)
    {
        this.theType = theType; 
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Yeah +1. Thanks for your sample code. I now understand it is a bad idea to use the static variable. Here I would do as you mentioned: to inject that in the constructor of the WebAPI. And now i am going to figure out how 'Delegate factories' works as suggested by john

Comment: Just add a few more info if anyone interested. it is mentioned in the [Best Practice](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/)..